# Excel - How to find how many times an item is ordered with another item

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a spreadsheet of lines shipped in a month, and in each row I have a delivery number and an item number. I'm trying to find a way to find what items are commonly ordered together.

For example:

[image: Table of item and delivery]

With an output of something along the lines of

[image: Times ordered with another item.]

I have access to Office, but not a whole lot of software beyond that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not all that experienced in Excel so most of what I tried was manipulating pivot tables to see if I could get the right results.Until a few weeks ago the most advanced function I'd used was =SUM(x:x), but my new job is working on what is essentially excel based database access, so I'm having to teach myself a lot of excel as I'm also not really given much direction.

Comment: I think this IS a job for pivot table. Any formula you are about to get will be crazy to make and crazier to maintain. Pivot tables are very simple and extremely powerful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IF($D2=E$1,"X",SUM(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDEX($A:$A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF($B$2:$B$15=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$15)*{1,1}))))),INDEX($A:$A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF($B$2:$B$15=E$1,ROW($B$2:$B$15)*{1,1}))))),0)))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This formula creates two arrays of the Delivery numbers:

```
MODE.MULT(IF($B$2:$B$15=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$15)*{1,1}))
```

Creates an array of row numbers where the value in D2 or E1 in the other half is found.

Those row number pass through the `N()` which forces the array to the `INDEX` Which then produces the array of Deliveries that delivered that item.

The `MATCH()` iterates the first array and checks if it is found in the second array.  If it is found it will return a number, if not an error.

The `ISNUMBER()` returns TRUE/FALSE based on the MATCH number or error.

The `--` turns the TRUE/FALSE into 1/0 and the SUM will sum that final array.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it works for the example! Now I'm just figuring out how to translate it to the actual spreadsheet. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please excuse my inexperience with Excel; What are the {1} and {1,1} for / what do they do?

Comment: They are arrays, the first an array with one item the next is an array with two items.

Comment: Okay, got it to work! ... Other than that Excel is grinding to a halt on testing it on a week of data (... at 2265 item numbers...)... And I've only pasted the formula into one column... I get the feeling applying it to a month of data is going to be a bit out of scope. Thank you very much for your help, though!